# How to configure mysql in spring boot with mybatis without using xml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

I am using spring boot with mybatis and mysql database in my application, i want to know how to configure database in my application using @configuration annotation.

This is my sample configuration file.

```html
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

 @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
 private String DB_DRIVER;

 @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
 private String DB_USERNAME;

 @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
 private String DB_PASSWORD;

 @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
 private String DB_URL;

 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {
  DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = null;
  try {
   dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
   dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
   dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
   dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.getMessage();
  }
  return dataSource;
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't... Remove the `@Configuration`... Put the properties in `application.properties` and spring Boot will automatically configure a datasource for you.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum it's working fine.

Comment: Hay, I also have a problem with db configuration in spring boot with myBatis, if you can help me to configure it, it would be a great help.
I have configure spring boot with annotation but myBatis is not getting configured.